# How to play sound from tcp stream in java

Tags: java, audio, streaming, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

There is another app that writes raw wav file on this socket.
The client starts and begins listening to the song which is currently playing.

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9595);
AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
```

> I get **javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input stream**
>
> Doc about AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream: "Obtains an audio input stream from the provided input stream. The stream must point to valid audio file data."

How to play sound from a TCP stream? Considering the client could not start listening from beginnig of the music.

Comment: You need to add more detail. There are lots of different ways in which this might not work. Are you hearing static? Nothing at all? Are you getting any exceptions thrown?

Answer (score 3):

Opening an AudioInputStream doesn't play the sound coming from this stream. You need to open a Clip to play the sound coming from the stream. I'm not an expert at all, but you should learn how to do it by reading [the Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public static int PORT = 3000;

    SourceDataLine _speaker;
    InputStream _streamIn;
    Socket _server;
    String _serverName = "127.0.0.1";
    boolean _running = true;

    public Client(String serverName) throws IOException,LineUnavailableException {
        this._serverName = serverName;
        init();
    }

    private void init() throws LineUnavailableException{
        //  specifying the audio format
        AudioFormat _format = new AudioFormat(8000.F,// Sample Rate
                16,     // Size of SampleBits
                1,      // Number of Channels
                true,   // Is Signed?
                false   // Is Big Endian?
        );

        //  creating the DataLine Info for the speaker format
        DataLine.Info speakerInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, _format);

        //  getting the mixer for the speaker
        _speaker = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(speakerInfo);
        _speaker.open(_format);
    }

    public void Start() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to server @" + _serverName + ":" + PORT);

            //  creating the socket and connect to the server
            _server = new Socket(_serverName, PORT);
            System.out.println("Connected to: " + _server.getRemoteSocketAddress());

            //  gettting the server stream
            _streamIn = _server.getInputStream();

            _speaker.start();

            byte[] data = new byte[8000];
            System.out.println("Waiting for data...");
            while (_running) {

                //  checking if the data is available to speak
                if (_streamIn.available() <= 0)
                    continue;   //  data not available so continue back to start of loop

                //  count of the data bytes read
                int readCount= _streamIn.read(data, 0, data.length);

                if(readCount > 0){
                    _speaker.write(data, 0, readCount);
                }
            }

            //honestly.... the control never reaches here.
            _speaker.drain();
            _speaker.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Refer to this project for a working TCP audio streaming project:
[https://github.com/sam016/J-Mic-Stream-Over-Socket/blob/master/Edit 00/](https://github.com/sam016/J-Mic-Stream-Over-Socket/blob/master/Edit%2000/SockMicClient/src/av/Client.java)

Refer to this specific file to get an idea on how to use TCP stream to play audio:
https://github.com/sam016/J-Mic-Stream-Over-Socket/blob/master/Edit%2000/SockMicClient/src/av/Client.java