# C++ to Java socket audio streaming

Tags: java, c++, sockets

Hello, I'm trying to build client-server audio streaming app. Server has to be written in C and communicate with client using sockets (TCP). Client will be written in javafx (actually tornadofx, but that doesn't relate to the problem)

My doubts concern the streaming part. Server has several audio files. I want to be able to start, stop, rewind, skip to another song in the client app. Java has AFAIK two classes to play audio - Clip and SourceDataLine. I don't think sending the whole song before playing is the way to go (Clip, large sound files) so I guess I should stick with SourceDataLine. My simple guess is that I should send fairly small portion of audio every time the client comes close to listening the last portion he received. (e.g I send 30 seconds and when client is on 25th second he sends request for more) Is that right? Is that doable in previously mentioned technologies?

Maybe something like ffmpeg could be useful here
https://github.com/avTranscoder/avTranscoder
But again, I have to communicate over tcp sockets only.

Comment: Have you done any research? I see many similar questions (with good answers) on SO. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718602/how-to-play-sound-from-tcp-stream-in-java

Comment: My research focused more on Clip and SourceDataLine. But I'm still not sure about one thing. Will I be able to rewind the song? And I need to differentiate between requests, what would be the best way to do this? e.g JSON, but I could not find much information about the proper way of handling different requests over sockets.

Comment: If you can rewind depends on your socket server and how it reads the audio file I guess, if you have random access to the file you can rewind pretty easily. I'm not sure what you mean by different request, you mean a network protocol where the client can send pre-defined commands like "play", "stop", "rewind by 10 seconds" etc? You have to implement you own protocol and figure out how to handle it. :)

Comment: Yes, I mean pre-defined commands. I thought there are some patterns designed for it, though. I guess you just clarified almost all my doubts, thank you :)