# Playing streamed music

Tags: java

I streaming music to client this way:

```
        String songFile= "/Users/test/Music/music/Essemm - Játékos.mp3";
        String eleresFajlnev = eleres;

        DataOutputStream dos = new 
        DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(eleresFajlnev);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[12 * 4096];

        int read;
        while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, read);
            dos.flush();
    }
```

Do you have any ideas on how to play streamed music without saving the music?
?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play sound from tcp stream in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718602/how-to-play-sound-from-tcp-stream-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stream music with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818155/stream-music-with-java)